# Does joining an online session with a different aiming mode on PC change anything?

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

So as the question asks i'm curious to know whether or not joining an online session changes my aim mode. Specifically whenever the game tells me that the session i'm joining is using a different targeting mode or something and asks if i'd like to change my target mode settings.

As far  as i can tell there are no settings inside the game settings that display or change the aiming modes available so i can only guess that it's available only when you have a controller plugged in?

I would like to keep my aim mode on free-aim and not have any aim assist at all. Will joining other sessions that require changing my aim mode to something other than free aim and if so how do i change it back?

Comment: I think it's just temporarily changed for the session. For example, that sometimes you are forced to use ego. And you can use Assist with controller, that's right.

Comment: It's not temporary, it sticks until you change it.

Comment: I think this has been changed, because while playing with my controller it used to tell me that the person hosting has another aim mode and asked if I wanted to change it and such... but now it doesn't ask anymore even though the host has no aim assist, and the aim assist is still on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only place to access the setting for aim mode is under the controller settings, which in turn you can only change when you are NOT in an online session (you have to return to single player). The setting is determined by the host (the server uses whatever the host had selected, and even the host cannot change the setting in an online session).

Joining an online session with a different aiming mode will warn you (as you have noticed), and it does in fact change the setting for you, and leaves it, even when you leave the session.

However, if you are using a keyboard and mouse the aiming mode does not affect how you aim. It does however put you at a severe disadvantage when playing with others who use controllers who will be able to take advantage of aim assist.

I have found it to be a frustratingly bloated process just to get back to free-aim again.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a mouse and keyboard, aim assist is unavailable. As such, leaving aim assist on might put you at a disadvantage against people with an aim-assisted controller.

Still, you will only get matched with people who have the same setting as you, and the game will prompt you when you try to join a game with a different targeting mode.

You can change targeting mode under Gamepad settings in the landing screen, or in single player.